# Removing a node that collides with player sprite

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to remove a node with the name “specialObstacle” in a levelUnit that is contained within a world node when the player collides with it, it succeeds but I have multiple nodes with the name “specialObstacle” in the multiple level units that all get removed as soon as a player collides with one. I’m trying to get the one that the player collides with to only be removed. my code is as follows:

**The Removal Code (Which is placed inside the contact code also):**

```
worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("levelUnit"){
        node, stop in

        let levelUnit:LevelUnit = node as! LevelUnit  //cast as an actual LevelUnit class

        levelUnit.enumerateChildNodesWithName("specialObstacle"){
            node, stop in


            node.removeFromParent()

        }

    }
```

**Obstacle Code: (Which is in its own class called Object: SKnode)**

```
 func createSpecialObject() {


        objectSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:imageName)
        self.addChild(objectSprite)

        objectSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: objectSprite.size.width / 3)
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.specialObjectDiamond.rawValue
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.specialObjectDiamond.rawValue

  }

        objectSprite.physicsBody!.friction = 1
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.0
        objectSprite.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

        self.zPosition = 400

    self.name = "specialObstacle"

    self.position = CGPointMake(objectSprite.size.width / 2 ,  0)

}
```

**Contact Code:**

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

   if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.specialObjectCoin.rawValue ) {

        **REMOVAL CODE HERE**

        numberOfCoins += 1
        print("number of Coins collected is \(numberOfCoins)")

    }

     else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.specialObjectCoin.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue  ) {

       **REMOVAL CODE HERE**

        numberOfCoins += 1
        print("number of Coins collected is \(numberOfCoins)")

    }
 }
```

I don't really know how to get it to only remove the node that my player collides with instead of all the other obstacles in the level units with the same name as "specialObstacle" being removed with it. Can Someone please provided insight into what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are removing an object from an array that you are iterating over. You can set the `contactTestBitMask` for the `specialObstacle` sprites and reference/remove the obstacles with `bodyA` or `bodyB` in `didBeginContact`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never want to remove during the `didBeginContact` phase. You can enter a position where you remove a node that has collided with 2 objects, removes on the first, then on the check second object, your program crashes due to the object not being there. Instead, you need to queue up all nodes that you will delete, and remove them during the `didFinishUpdate` phase

```
var nodesToRemove = [SKNode]()

override func didBeginContact() 
{

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.specialObjectCoin.rawValue ) 
    {

        **REMOVAL CODE HERE**
        nodesToRemove.append(contact.bodyB.node)
        numberOfCoins += 1
        print("number of Coins collected is \(numberOfCoins)")

    }

     else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.specialObjectCoin.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue  ) 
     {

       **REMOVAL CODE HERE**
        nodesToRemove.append(contact.bodyA.node)
        numberOfCoins += 1
        print("number of Coins collected is \(numberOfCoins)")

    }  
}

override func didFinishUpdate() 
{   
     nodesToRemove.forEach(){$0.removeFromParent()}   
     nodesToRemove = [SKNode]()

}
```

Comment: Also, I would like to note,  you may want to have some kind of willDelete or  isDead flag going on if yo do not want your object to hit multiple times

Comment: Another side note,  any time you see yourself writing the same functionality twice, ask yourself: "How do I simplify this to reduce redundancy?"   You will find it better in the long run when you only have to change the code in 1 location (E.G.  You make coins value 10 instead of 1,  you now have 2 spots to change this)

Comment: Is there anyway I could not use the removal code or make it so I don't have to re write it again? and why do you suggest to never remove during the beginning stages of a contact? because steve's answer above solves my problem easily and with minimal code..

Comment: Already explained why before I show the code, it literally takes 2 seconds to change from Steves answer to my answer, and my way is safer code handling (Providing you used your if statement and didn't use his switch statement, which I am not a fan of, but for different reasons)

Comment: The reason I do not like his switch statement, is because you are forcing the category to only be 1 case,  which defeats the purpose of the masks.  So let's say you have a star man ability.  You can add this by making a  category for starman,  so now your player is Player | Starman.  Uh Oh,  your case statement now fails, so you need to include another case statement for Starman.  When designing logically,  the coin should not care whether or not the player is in starman mode, so you shouldn't have a case that checks it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Are those 'if' statements going to work if a body has multiple categories? It's doing a simple equality test between the categoryBitMask and the category value, which won't match. If you're checking if coin has hit the player (with or without starman ability), then (assume nodaA is player and nodeB is coin) contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue won't work because contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask will be something like '0011' (if player is 0001 and starman is 0010) which won't match BodyType.player.rawValue (0001). You need to do some bit checking.

Comment: @Steve Ives The way the OP is doing his code no,  I use & to compare flags. Mask & category = category

Comment: Ok - that's what I though. I'd like to come up with a readable, watertight code template for this. Also, have you seen issues when removing node from didBeginContact (hence your use of an array to be processed later) or is this a theoretical problem?

Comment: It is a real problem,  it can actually be seen a few times on SO

Comment: @Steve Ives The issue is most cases you do not have 1 sprite colliding with 2 objects, but I am a strong believer of writing code to handle all problems, not most problems, and future proofing it, unless there is a benefit to not doing so( In this case, there is no benefit due to the minimal efforts to implement)

Comment: @Steve Ives,  great example is you hit a coin and goomba.  If you do the kill in a didbegincontact,  then your game has inconsistent rules,  sometimes you are awarded a coin and then death,  sometimes just death

Comment: Well, one sprite can't collide with 2 objects at the same time in SpriteKit.  I was looking for some documentation that SpriteKit can see a sprite collide with one object and then a second object before calling didBeginContact for the first collision, which could(would?) lead to problems if you remove the sprite and then SK attempts to call dBC for the 2nd collision.

Comment: @Steve Ives,  a sprite can collide with 2 objects at the same time,  you just can't evaluate the problem of both collisions at the same time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116789/discussion-between-steve-ives-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: your case is now an if statement with the word case instead

Answer (score 0):

When `didBeginContact` is called, you are given the 2 nodes that collided, so it's easy to remove the right one:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

       let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

       switch contactMask

       case BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.specialObjectCoin.rawValue :

          // The player and the coin have contacted
          let coin = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.specialObjectCoin.rawValue ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
          coin.removeFromParent()
          numberOfCoins += 1
          print("number of Coins collected is \(numberOfCoins)")

       default:
          print("Other contact detected")
    }
```

Comment: Steve this code don't work, it remove player instead of specialObjectCoin

Comment: Thanks for your help i just changed the bodytype from player to specialobjectCoin and it worked thanks

Comment: @Astrum This is not the correct mode to do it, look the Knight0fDragon answers

Comment: I just changed it @Alessandro Ornano

Comment: Sorry guys - copied code from elsewhere. Should now be correct.

Comment: Not sure why somebody would down vote this,  it is a valid answer

Comment: As Knight pointed out, the switch/case won't work if your categoryBitMasks contain more than one '1' i.e you are putting nodes in multiple categories. you then need to do some more complicated bit checking.